# How can I prevent my ServiceWorker from intercepting cross-origin requests?

Tags: cross-domain, service-worker

I am trying to clean up some code on my application https://git.sequentialread.com/forest/sequentialread-password-manager

I am using a ServiceWorker to enable the application to run offline -- however, I noticed that the ServiceWorker is intercepting cross-origin requests to backblazeb2.com.  The app makes these cross origin requests as a part of its normal operation.

You can see [here](https://git.sequentialread.com/forest/sequentialread-password-manager/src/8bd304d31f69b383680a71fde67fbdc698411f4e/static/application.js#L17) how I am registering the ServiceWorker:

```
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/serviceworker.js', {scope: "/"}).then(
      (reg) => {
         ...
```

And inside the `serviceworker.js` code, I [manually avoid caching any requests to backblazeb2.com](https://git.sequentialread.com/forest/sequentialread-password-manager/src/8bd304d31f69b383680a71fde67fbdc698411f4e/static/serviceworker.js#L54):

```
        ...
        return fetch(event.request).then(response => {
          const url = new URL(event.request.url);
          const isServerStorage = url.pathname.startsWith('/storage');
          const isVersion = url.pathname == "/version";
          const isBackblaze = url.host.includes('backblazeb2.com');
          const isPut = event.request.method == "PUT";
          if(!isServerStorage && !isVersion && !isBackblaze && !isPut) {

            ... // cache the response
```

However, this seems silly, I wish there was a way to limit the ServiceWorker to only intercept requests for the current origin.

I already tried inserting the origin into the `scope` property during registration, but this didn't work:

```
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/serviceworker.js', {scope: window.location.origin}).then(
      (reg) => {
         ...
```

It was behaving the same way.  I am assuming that perhaps this is because there are CORS headers present on the responses from backblazeb2.com, making those requests "technically" within the "scope" of the current origin ?

One idea I had, I could serve a permanent redirect from `/` to `/static/index.html`  and then configure the serviceworker with a scope of `/static`, meaning it would only cache resources in that folder.  But that seems like an ugly hack I should not have to do.

Is there a clean and "correct" way to do this??

Comment: I actually just tried the solution where I move all the static assets including the landing page into a specific folder on the server (called `/app`)  and then pass `{scope: "/app/"}` when I register the service worker. I can see the scope on the service worker in the debugger: https://picopublish.beta.sequentialread.com/files/sw_scope.png

However, its STILL intercepting the cross origin requests as well as the requests for files outside of `/app/`.  What gives!! It really seems like this isn't supposed to be happening...

Comment: Can you share your service worker code, I would like to look into how you are caching your resources. Is it a static one or dynamics?

Comment: I already did in my answer, but here it is again: https://git.sequentialread.com/forest/sequentialread-password-manager/src/branch/master/static/serviceworker.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fetch event in the service worker has a property on the request called "mode." This property allows you to check if the mode was set to "cors."

Here is an example of how to prevent cors requests.

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', (e) =>
{
    if(e.request.method !== 'GET')
    {
        return false;
    }

    if(e.request.mode === 'navigate')
    {
        e.respondWith(caches.match('index.html'));
        return false;
    }
    else if(e.request.mode === 'cors')
    {
        return false;
    }

    const response = this.fetchFile(e);
    e.respondWith(response);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the answer is, you can't do this. the serviceworker api won't let you.

Someone explained it to me as "the `scope` for the serviceworker limits where FROM the requests can be intercepted, not where TO the requests can be intercepted. So in otherwords, if I register a serviceworker at `/app/`, then a javascript from `/` or `/foo/` will be able to make requests without them being intercepted.

It turns out that actually what I **REALLY** needed was to understand how service worker error handling works.

In the old version of my app, when the `fetch()` promise rejected, [my code would return null](https://git.sequentialread.com/forest/sequentialread-password-manager/src/dc38c23a4aae5ebcd643a6a7c37721563406bb23/static/serviceworker.js#L78).

```
        return fetch(event.request).then(response => {
          ...blahblahblah...
        }).catch( e => {
          ....
          return null;
        });
```

This was bad news bears and it was causing me to want to skip the serviceworker. what I didn't understand was; its not the serviceworkers fault *per se* as much as the fact that my serviceworker did not handle errors correctly. So the solution was to handle errors better.

This is what I did. I [introduced a new route on the server called `/error`](https://git.sequentialread.com/forest/sequentialread-password-manager/src/9f15d65bfc39bc39c5d0630c3f6b5c26710d3fe9/server.go#L194) that always returns the string "serviceworker request failed".

```
    http.HandleFunc("/error", func(response http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
        response.WriteHeader(200)
        fmt.Fprint(response, "serviceworker request failed")
    })
```

And then I [made sure to cache that endpoint](https://git.sequentialread.com/forest/sequentialread-password-manager/src/9f15d65bfc39bc39c5d0630c3f6b5c26710d3fe9/static/serviceworker.js#L11) when the service worker is installed.

```
self.addEventListener('install', event => {
  event.waitUntil(clients.get(event.clientId).then(client => {
    return caches.open(cacheVersion).then(cache => {
      return cache.addAll([
        '/',
        '/error',
        ....
```

Finally, when the serviceworker `fetch()` promise rejects, I [fall back to returning the cached version](https://git.sequentialread.com/forest/sequentialread-password-manager/src/9f15d65bfc39bc39c5d0630c3f6b5c26710d3fe9/static/serviceworker.js#L79).

```
        return fetch(event.request).then(response => {
          ...blahblahblah...
        }).catch( e => {
          ....
          return caches.match('/error');
        });
```

I got the idea from the [MDN serviceworker example project](https://github.com/mdn/sw-test) which [does a similar thing](https://github.com/mdn/sw-test/blob/gh-pages/sw.js#L37) and simply returns a cached image of darth vader if the `fetch()` promise rejects.

This allowed me to gracefully handle these errors and retry instead of silently failing. I simply had to make sure that my code does the right thing [when it encounters an http response that matches the literal string `"serviceworker request failed"`](https://git.sequentialread.com/forest/sequentialread-password-manager/src/master/static/application.js#L358).

```
  const requestFailedBytes = app.sjcl.codec.bytes.fromBits(app.sjcl.codec.utf8String.toBits("serviceworker request failed"));

  ...

      var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
      ....
      httpRequest.onloadend = () => {
        ...
              if(app.cryptoService.uint8ArrayEquals(new Uint8Array(httpRequest.response), requestFailedBytes)) {
                reject(false);
                return
              }
```

Comment: If you are using "Cache only" caching strategy then you can filter out the request based on that in fetch event handler.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean this? https://serviceworke.rs/strategy-cache-only_service-worker_doc.html

Comment: I think my problem was when my fetch event handler returned a promise which resolved to null or undefined, it broke my app. I had to make the fetch event handler return a valid http response, even when it failed because of a truely exceptional network error.

Comment: Yes, I mean that link strategy. Are you using the same? If yes, then what you can do that is you filter out request in fetch event handler before invoking fetch calls. That way you dont need those extra handler at all.